# What is the difference between freeze_graph and write_graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Google says:[image]

But as far as I know if I would like to use tensorflow inference i need protobuf file (.pb) which I can get using freeze_graph method. So what is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As a heads-up, `freeze_graph` is generally deprecated in TensorFlow 2.x. You should be using [Saved Models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) for the same functionality in Tensorflow 2.x.  I'll be answering this question from the perspective of TensorFlow 1.x.*

Before understanding the difference between the two, you need to know how a TensorFlow model is shaped.

Each TensorFlow model is composed of a graph data structure, which contains the Operation objects, which are the units of computation, and the Tensor objects, which are the units of data that flow between them.

However, a graph alone is not enough to do anything like inference. When you train a model, it learns and optimizes a unique set of parameters for the different parts of your graph.

A PB file, then, includes both of these parts - the graph that represents the structure of the model, and the parameters that the model has learned through training.

So back to the original question - what's the difference between `write_graph` and `freeze_graph`?

- `write_graph` writes out the graph of the model (the structure) into the PB file.

  - This does not require any training, so it doesn't include any parameters the model may have learned.
- `freeze_graph` takes the trained parameters of the model from a training checkpoint and saves that as well to the PB file.